# Can I move my D drive to a "D" partition on my C drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

My D drive (a 1TB HDD) is getting older and it's starting to act up (recently windows had to repair it before booting up).

So I'm wondering, can I change its drive letter from "D" to "E" so that I can create a "D" partition on my C drive (a 2TB SSD), and move all files from my previous "D" drive to my "D" partition. In theory, all the file paths should be the same, so all installed programs should still work, right?

Technical details:
Laptop: ASUS FX503-VD
OS: Windows 10 (home)
SSD: Samsung 980 PRO 2TB
HDD: ST1000LM035-1RK172

Comment: So that if your SSD fails, you lose it all? Why not get a replacement for the external drive?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen good point, I thought of my SSD as being new fast and safe, but it's probably not as safe as I thought it is. Luckily I do make backups on some external drives

Comment: I used to have an external D: drive which I cloned onto an internal disk and labeled the internal disk as D:. This worked fine for static files but anything which was linked to a program install like Steam ended up needing re-installation. I don't remember the exact error or troubles so take my comment as a cautionary anecdote.

Comment: @SP4CEBAR Depending on the application, SSDs can have a much shorter lifespan than HDDs. Some of the highest-density ones are only rated for a few hundred writes! I like to have both a solid-state drive and a hard drive in my computers, not just for cost reasons.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen If you're not making regular backups you're going to lose it all sooner or later no matter what kind of drive you have or what it's lifespan is.

Comment: Terminology: I think you mean "move D: to a new partition on the disk that holds C:".  You can't make a partition inside a filesystem, so it makes little sense to talk about making a partition on you "C drive".  Windows drive letters refer to filesystems, typically inside a partition, not to the whole disk that contains them.  (Your boot drive probably already has an EFI boot partition, and probably a Windows recovery partition, but Windows doesn't mount (assign drive letters) to those by default.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general your scheme will work. However, you need to copy the
files so as to keep all their properties.

I would suggest doing it this way :

- Create the new partition and assign it a temporary drive-letter such as F:
- Run a Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Copy the files using the utility
  [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) :

  ```
  robocopy /e /copyall d: f:
  ```
- Verify that the data was fully copied
- Change the drive-letter of D to E, then of F to D
- Reboot
- Verify that applications installed on the new D still work
- Retire the HDD as backup in case errors are found
  in the future.

Comment: I just suggest to add a point after. As (if) you can buy a another 2TB drive and backup regularly the whole primary SSD.

Answer (score 5):

It should work fine. I would copy the files over first, instead of moving them.

Then rename the drives. Depending on what you have running, you may have to do the renaming in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the drive letter of your D drive to another available letter (such as E), and then create a new partition on your C drive and assign it the drive letter D. All file paths should remain the same, so any installed programs that reference files on the D drive should still work.

However, before making any changes, I would recommend backing up all important data on both drives to an external storage device or cloud storage service. This will ensure that you don't lose any data in case something goes wrong during the process.

To change the drive letter of your D drive, follow these steps:

1. Open the Disk Management utility by right-clicking the Start button and selecting "Disk Management".
2. In the list of disks, find your D drive (the ST1000LM035-1RK172) and right-click it.
3. Select "Change Drive Letter and Paths".
4. Click the "Change" button and select a new available drive letter (such as E).
5. Click "OK" to save the changes.

To create a new partition on your C drive and assign it the drive letter D, follow these steps:

1. Open the Disk Management utility again.
2. In the list of disks, find your C drive (the Samsung 980 PRO 2TB) and right-click it.
3. Select "Shrink Volume".
4. Enter the amount of space you want to allocate to the new partition (in MB) and click "Shrink".
5. You should now see an unallocated space on your C drive. Right-click it and select "New Simple Volume".
6. Follow the wizard to create the new partition and assign it the drive letter D.

Comment: Like your answers on Stack Overflow, this answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT

Answer (score 1):

I've done stuff like this all the time.  Personally, what I would do is:

- Get a new drive that's the same size or larger than your current D drive, (preferably larger).
- Download cloning software, such as [CloneZilla - Alternative Stable](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)
- Use something like [YUMI UEFI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) to make a bootable USB drive.
- Get size, make, serial information from your drives.
- Power down the system.
- Add the new drive, (disconnect your other drives, not necessary, but a good safety precaution).
- Boot into the USB drive and start YUMI or Rufus.
- Run CloneZilla or other cloning software.
- Do a direct copy from old drive to new drive, (use information acquired from above to help you know which drive is which).  If your new drive is larger, your cloning software will hopefully not allow you to overwrite the old drive with the new one, a good safety feature.
- Power down system, remove old drive, (and reconnect any other drives you disconnected).
- Power on system.
- Make sure Windows maps the new drive to D drive.
- Reboot just in case.
- Profit.

I usually get a larger drive if possible since I have carelessly overwritten an old drive with the empty contents of a new drive.  That hurts.